# Nameservers route 53 and renew domain registration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

some time ago I registered a domain with Netsons, now I changed nameservers to route53 and it points to my website on EC2. Now I don't know if i have to pay Netsons every year for registration or not!!! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will always pay for domain registration each year. Route53 is only provides DNS and not domain registration.